# ¿Por qué no puedo eliminar los elementos del DOM que cree con jQuery?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, input

estoy agregando inputs al presionar el botón agregar y también quiero eliminarlos al presionar el menos. El primero no lo quiero quitar por eso le puse una clase de `no-remove`, el problema es que solo puedo eliminar los que cree en el **html**, pero no los que cree en el **jQuery**.

¿Hay una explicación para esto? Quizás hay otra forma de eliminar los elementos que creé en el **jQuery**, intente usar `remove()` y tampoco se elimina. No se que estoy haciendo mal:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
       
       $('.remove').click(function(){

           $(this).css("display","none");


       })


       $('.add').click(function(){


         const formulario = $(".formulario");
         const div = $("<div>");
         const input = $("<input>");
        

         div.addClass("remove");
         div.text("-");
         
         input.attr("type" , "text");
         input.attr("name" , "");
         input.attr("placeholder" , "Ingrese un nombre");

         formulario.append(div);
         div.append(input);

       })

         
       
})
```

```css
.remove , .no-remove{

    font-size: 25px;
    font-weight: bold;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.add{

    cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/index.css">
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/index.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

    <form class="formulario">
        <div class="no-remove">-
            <input type="text" name="" placeholder="Ingrese un nombre">
        </div>
        <div class="remove">-
            <input type="text" name="" placeholder="Ingrese un nombre">
        </div>
    </form>
     <br>
    <input type="submit" class="add" value="Agregar" />

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Lee [esta respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/370344/agregar-boton-por-fila-en-tabla/370652#370652) ahí se explica porqué solo funciona con los elementos que ya existen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lo que te esta pasando es que cuando creas elementos con **jQuery** en tiempo de ejecuccion no están disponibles en el **DOM** y los eventos que tenemos asociados a esos elementos no van a funcionar.

Para ello tenemos que utilizar la `delegación de eventos` [Más info aqui](https://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation).

Básicamente hay que utilizar un selector de **jQuery** sobre un elemento que ya este en el **DOM**. Puedes hacerlo de la siguiente manera:

```
$('.formulario').on('click', '.remove', function() {
   $(this).parent().hide();
})
```

Si te fijas, estamos haciendo el selector sobre la clase `.formulario` (que ya estaba en el **DOM**) y luego en el `.on()` le decimos que mire el evento `click` sobre la clase `.remove`. También te serviría hacerlo sobre `document` o `body`.

Aparte de eso, hay otro error en tu ejemplo. El evento `.click()` lo tienes aplicado sobre el `<div>` entero, asi que al hacer click sobre cualquier parte del `<div>` se ocultaría. Deberías de añadirle una clase al simbolo de menos (-) y aplicar el evento sobre ella.

Aplicando las dos cosas que te comento, tu ejemplo debería de quedar algo asi:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  $('.formulario').on('click', '.remove', function() {
    $(this).parent().hide();
  })

  $('.add').click(function() {


    const formulario = $(".formulario");
    const div = $("<div>");
    const input = $("<input>");

    input.attr("type", "text");
    input.attr("name", "");
    input.attr("placeholder", "Ingrese un nombre");

    formulario.append(div);
    div.append("<span class='remove'>-</span>")
    div.append(input);

  })



})
```

```css
.remove,
.no-remove {
  font-size: 25px;
  font-weight: bold;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.add {
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title></title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>

  <form class="formulario">
    <div>
      <span class="no-remove">-</span>
      <input type="text" name="" placeholder="Ingrese un nombre">
    </div>
    <div>
      <span class="remove">-</span>
      <input type="text" name="" placeholder="Ingrese un nombre">
    </div>
  </form>
  <br>
  <input type="submit" class="add" value="Agregar" />

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Muchas gracias, no lo podía solucionar, me sirvió de gran ayuda, Saludos Aitor :D !