# insertAdjacentHTML() en window.onresize: no entiendo qué sucede

Tags: javascript, html

He encontrado miles de veces la solución a alguna duda en mi etapa de aprendizaje en esta gran comunidad y su hermana en inglés, pero, esta vez estoy perdido.

Pongo un caso simple, ya que mi código es bastante más complejo.

Quiero insertar un *item* a una lista de forma dinámica a través de `insertAdjacentHTML()` cuando la ventana tiene ciertas dimensiones.

Una vez agregado, hago un *listener* a traves de su clase y para ejemplo llamo a un `alert()`. Hasta aquí funciona perfecto, pero la cuestión es que también he implementado la misma función de agregar el *item*, pero cuando la ventana se redimensiona `(window.onresize)` y a pesar de usar la misma función, si bien se inserta el *item*, no lo reconoce el evento `click`, o sea, si reconoce el `href`, pero no reconoce ni la clase ni el **id**.

Dejo el ejemplo:

```html
<ul>
  <li><a href="#" class="general" id="item1">ITEM 1</a></li>
  <li><a href="#" class="general" id="item2">ITEM 2</a></li>
</ul>

<script>
  window.onresize = redimensiona;
  let agregado = false;
  if (window.innerWidth < 787 && agregado == false) {
    agrega();
  }

  function redimensiona() {
    if (window.innerWidth < 787 && agregado == false) {
      agrega();
    }
  }

  function agrega() {
    let referencia = document.getElementById("item2");
    referencia.insertAdjacentHTML('afterend', '<li><a href="#" class="general" id="item3">ITEM 3</a></li> ');
    agregado = true;
  }
  $(".general").click(function() {
    alert();
    console.log(this.id);
  });
</script>
```

Comment: No lo reconoce porque el elemento todavía no existe cuando asignas el evento; debes delegarlo. Revisa [esta respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/370344/agregar-boton-por-fila-en-tabla/370652#370652)

Answer (score 1):

Me fije lo de la delegacion y solo cambiando:

```
$(".general").click(function() {
alert();
console.log(this.id);
```

});

por:

```
$(document).on("click",".general", function () {
    console.log(this.id);
  });
```

se soluciono

Comment: Exacto, porque con el primero, se asigna el evento solo a los elementos que YA EXISTEN y no toma en cuenta los que agregas posteriormente. Con el segundo, cada que se hace un clic en el documento, se analiza si el elemento tiene la clase especificada para ejecutar la función, entonces no importa si ya existía al momento de asignar el evento o se agregó después.