# Problemas para cargar datatables en chrome

Tags: javascript, datatables

ayuda

Estoy implementando datatables para cargar datos de mi db en una tabla, donde agregare las opciones editar y eliminar registro por medio de un botón.

Por alguna razón datatables carga después de la carga de la pagina y por lo tanto no puedo acceder a la clase btnEditaRegistro que tengo en cada uno de los registros.

Hice la prueba de quemar en el html los registros de prueba tal y como deberían llegar de la BD, sin usar datatables. Funciona sin ningún problema

Si doy clic en mi botón de editar no pasa nada, ni si quiera la consola arroja algún error

Así mi código..

mi tabla

```
<table class="table table-hover table-bordered" id="tableRol">
                        <thead>
                            <tr>
                                <th>#</th>
                                <th>Nombre</th>
                                <th>Descripción</th>
                                <th>Status</th>
                                <th class="text-right" >Opciones</th>
                            </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody>
                            
                        </tbody>
                    </table>
```

js

```
let tableRoles;

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded',()=>{

tableRoles = $("#tableRol").dataTable({

    "aProcessing":true,
    "aServerSide":true,
    "language":{
        "url":"//cdn.datatables.net/plug-ins/1.10.20/i18n/Spanish.json"
    },
    "ajax":{
        "url": base_url+"/Roles/getRoles",
        "dataSrc":""
    },
    "columns":[

        {"data":"idRol"},
        {"data":"nombreRol"},
        {"data":"descripcionRol"},
        {"data":"statusRol"},
        {"data":"opciones"},

    ],

    "resonsieve":"true",
    "bDestroy":true,
    "iDisplayLength":10,
    "order":[[0,"desc"]]

  });

 });

$('#tableRol').DataTable();

window.addEventListener('load',function(){
    fEditaModal();
},false);

function fEditaModal(){
    alert("prueba 1");

    let btnEditaRol = document.querySelectorAll(".btnEditaRegistro ");

    btnEditaRol.forEach(function(btnEditaRol){

        btnEditaRol.addEventListener("click",()=>{

            alert("hola");

        });

    });

    alert(btnEditaRol.length);
    alert("prueba fin");

}
```

Comparto mi js en footer

```
    <script src="<?=media()?>/js/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>    
    <script src="<?=media()?>/js/popper.min.js"></script>
    <script src="<?=media()?>/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="<?=media()?>/js/main.js"></script>
    <script src="<?=media()?>/js/awesome.js"></script>
    <script src="<?=media()?>/js/scripts.js"></script>

    <script src="<?=media()?>/js/plugins/pace.min.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="<?=media()?>/js/plugins/sweetalert.min.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="<?=media()?>/js/plugins/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="<?=media()?>/js/plugins/dataTables.bootstrap.min.js"></script>

    <script src="<?=media()?>/js/roles.js"></script>

  </body>
 </html>
```

Al momento de la carga se ejecuta el alert prueba 1, alert hola no se ejecuta, alert btnEditaRol da 0 (cuando debería mostrar 10)

Cabe mencionar que esto pasa en google chrome y edge, firefox funciona bien (no he probado mas navegadores)

Que puedo intentar? gracias por su ayuda

Comment: Hola, podes poner la parte de tu html donde estas cargando tus archivos javascript?

Comment: Estás cargando los datos por AJAX y, en teoría, en algunos navegadores podría funcionar porque la alerta crea una pausa que permite terminar de cargar el contenido. Para que funcione en todos, deberías delegar los eventos. Revisa [esta respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/370344/agregar-boton-por-fila-en-tabla/370652#370652) seguramente te servirá.

Comment: hola @jdromero88 agregue mi carga de archivos js, gracias!

Comment: gracias @Triby lo revisaré; de hecho pasa lo mismo si quito los alert

Comment: @Triby si ya intente delegando los eventos con jquery y me funciona ( $(document).on('click', '.btnborrar', function().. ), el problema es que quería intentarlo con javascript puro , que es cuando tengo el inconveniente :\

Comment: ¡Compadre, Datatables es jQuery! ¿Qué caso tiene mezclar con Javascript puro?

Comment: gracias! quiero ir dejando jquery por eso ando tratando con js XD @Triby

Comment: Hola @jdromero88, te había dado rechazar la edición porque pensé que habías agregado código nuevo en la publicación, pero no me había percatado que parte de su pregunta se encontraba en una respuesta que publicó. Lo tendré en cuenta para la próxima y espero otro usuario la pueda aprobar. Está bien tu edición.

Comment: Hola @cassini, ¿puedes revisar la solicitud de edición? Aunque sería bueno que se la aprobaras. Eso ayudará a completar tu pregunta.

Comment: gracias @DavidE.LunaM. aprobé la edición

Comment: gracias @DavidE.LunaM.

Comment: Sigo sin entender porque no quieres usar jQuery para asignar los eventos, lo vas a necesitar para **acceder a los datos de la fila** a la que pertenece el botón que recibe el clic y, si el navegador ya cargó la librería, no tiene sentido dejar de usar las herramientas disponibles para "hacerlo a mano".

Comment: gracias  @Triby me gusta complicarme la vida con javascript puro XD, pero creo que en esta ocasión optare por volver a jquery. De igual modo puedes obtener los datos de cada fila con javascript puro accediendo al atributo con el id y mandar los datos con el objeto XMLHttpRequest y sus metodos open y send

Answer (score 0):

como va? El problema esta en la sintaxis de tu forEach...

El método [.forEach()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) te va a ejecutar una función por cada elemento en tu array.
Necesita dos parámetros el elemento y la función a ejecutar.

En tu caso te falto pasar el primer parámetro vos pasaste directo la función.

Espero que el siguiente código te sirva de guía.

```js
function fEditaModal(){
    alert("prueba 1");
    let btnEditaRol = document.querySelectorAll(".btnEditaRegistro ");
    // Este es una ejemplo de la sintaxis
    btnEditaRol.forEach ( button => console.log(button.innerText ))
    
    // Este es otro ejemplo pasandole los argumentos opcionales
    btnEditaRol.forEach ( (button, index) => console.log(button.innerText, "estoy en la posicion " + index ))
    
    btnEditaRol.forEach( button => {
      button.addEventListener("click",  () => alert("Hola") );
    });
    alert(btnEditaRol.length);
    alert("prueba fin");

}

/***

function fEditaModal(){
    alert("prueba 1");

    let btnEditaRol = document.querySelectorAll(".btnEditaRegistro ");
    El problema esta en la syntaxis de tu forEach...
    forEach te va a ejecutar una funcion por cada elemento en tu array.
    y necesita dos parametros el elemento y la funcion a ejecutar
    Este es una ejemplo de la sintaxis
    btnEditaRol.forEach ( button => console.log(button.innerText ))
    
    Este es otro ejemplo pasandole los argumentos opcionales
    btnEditaRol.forEach ( (button, index) => console.log(button.innerText, "estoy en la posicion " + index ))
    
    btnEditaRol.forEach(function(btnEditaRol){

        btnEditaRol.addEventListener("click",()=>{

            alert("hola");

        });

    });

    alert(btnEditaRol.length);
    alert("prueba fin");

}

***/

fEditaModal()
```

```css
.btnEditaRegistro {
  color:#fff;
  background-color:red;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: .5rem;
  font-weight: bold;
  border: 0;
  border-radius: 10%;
}
```

```html
<button class="btnEditaRegistro"> Editar </button>
<button class="btnEditaRegistro"> Editar </button>
<button class="btnEditaRegistro"> Editar </button>
<button class="btnEditaRegistro"> Editar </button>
<button class="btnEditaRegistro"> Editar </button>
<button class="btnEditaRegistro"> Editar </button>
```

Comment: gracias por la ayuda seguro es eso, lo revisare gracias de nuevo